# Writing to stdin within the program?

Tags: python, stdin

Is there a way of doing something like `sys.stdin.write("text")` inside the program, to simulate a text being enter from a user,
instead of using `input()` or equivalent and wait for the user to type something?

I am asking because I have a bug in my program that I am unable to fix, the bug was posted yesterday yet no answers got till now, and this is my last resort.

(Windows XP, Python3.3)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various hacks to accomplish this, e.g.

```
from io import StringIO
import sys

sys.stdin = StringIO("user says hello!")
```

This should work across modules. Similarly, you can replace `sys.stdin` with a stream attached to a series of canned user inputs.

Comment: could you add more explanation to this code please? I know I should read about this module for better understanding, but could you add more details?

Comment: @user2162550: the main thing this code does is replace `sys.stdin` with a different stream, in effect redirecting it. `StringIO` is a special type of pseudo-file that reads from a string.